# Copy, insert and delete a given cell

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do here is taking a given cell, copying its value and deleting the cell after pasting its value to the newly inserted cell. User gives input about which cell to delete and which cell to insert the new cell upon.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Test() 
   Dim rngDeleteCell As Range
   Dim rngInsertCell As Range
   
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rngDeleteCell = Application. InputBox( _
          "Select the cell to delete", _
          Type:=8)
   If rngDeleteCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Set rngInsertCell = Application. InputBox( _
          "Select the cell to insert the new cell upon", _
          Type:=8)
   If rngInsertCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 

On Error GoTo 0

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
 .Range(rngInsertCell).Insert xlShiftDown
 .Range(rngDeleteCell).Copy Destination:=Range(rngInsertCell) 
 .Range(rngDeleteCell).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
End With
End Sub
```

However, when I run the code I receive Run-time error:'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: `rngInsertCell` and `rngDeleteCell` are alread ranges - use them without `.Range(xx)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and doing that raises another run-time error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my goal by adapting Notus_Panda's code. To be more clear, I wanted to switch the cell values in an iterative database. Column number is adjustable.

```html
Sub TestInsertDelete()
   Dim rngDeleteCell As Range
   Dim rngInsertCell As Range
   
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rngDeleteCell = Application.InputBox( _
          "Select the cell to delete", _
          Type:=8)
   If rngDeleteCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Set rngInsertCell = Application.InputBox( _
          "Select the cell to insert the new cell upon", _
          Type:=8)
   If rngInsertCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo 0

 rngInsertCell.Insert xlShiftDown
 Cells(rngInsertCell.Row - 1, 2).Value = rngDeleteCell.Value
 rngDeleteCell.ClearContents
 rngDeleteCell.Value = Cells(rngInsertCell.Row, 2).Value
 rngInsertCell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the desired effect you had in mind, seems a bit odd shifting all the values up like that:

[image: odd outcome]

The values get shifted upwards with an empty space keeping the values below it where they were..

Your code adjusted used:

```
Sub TestInsertDelete()
   Dim rngDeleteCell As Range
   Dim rngInsertCell As Range
   
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rngDeleteCell = Application.InputBox( _
          "Select the cell to delete", _
          Type:=8)
   If rngDeleteCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Set rngInsertCell = Application.InputBox( _
          "Select the cell to insert the new cell upon", _
          Type:=8)
   If rngInsertCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo 0

 rngInsertCell.Insert xlShiftDown
 rngDeleteCell.Copy Destination:=rngInsertCell
 rngDeleteCell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
End Sub
```

If this weird result is what you were going for, then good(?), if not, please clarify how it was meant to be. If Ike wants credit for clarifying the `.Range(xx)` I don't mind :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I actually had in mind was copying the value in the newly inserted cell. So shifting the places of the values are more wanted than keeping values where they were.

Comment: You know you don't need to insert a new cell to copy a value, right? Regardless, the code I gave does just that so hopefully you can use it.